# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working for search results

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have table view and when I touch cell, detailTextLabel appears. I implemented search, but didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work for search results array. I just copied the code from the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
    {
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
        self.searchResults = [self.cards filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    }

    -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
    {
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                                   scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                          objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                         selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

        return YES;
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Card Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            Card *card = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"name"]]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"otherSide"]]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;

        } else {
            Card *card = [self.cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"name"]]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"otherSide"]]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;
        }

        return cell;
    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Card Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            Card *card = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"name"]]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"otherSide"]]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            Card *card = [self.cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"name"]]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [card valueForKey:@"otherSide"]]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;
        }

        [self.tableView endUpdates];

    }
```

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Have you set the delegate?

Comment: It means, that when I select item from self.cards array, detailTextLabel appears, but it doesn't happen when I select an item from the searchResults array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some notable differences between `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` creates a cell or gets a existing of the cell stack and you will enter the properties and return it before its displayed. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you don't get that cell in the parameters, so you have to call the `[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath]` instead of `[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Card Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` to get the cell and set the properties.

Also make sure you have set the delegate of the tableview.

Comment: I've just set <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> in header file, so how should I call [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath] in didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Sorry, I'm a junior developer.